# Using Jsoup to POST login & cookie data

Tags: post, cookies, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to log into my account to this web site, using java & jsoup. But no matter what changes I've made here & there, I just return the login page as a response. I must have something wrong?

I've used Firefox's Firebug, Chrome, and Fiddler to see what values are being sent. I've looked at some of the other answers here on StackOverflow on jsoup, and believe I'm following the correct procedure. If anyone can see my errors, I'd appreciate the help.

```
    String loginURL = "http://members.permaculturedesigncourse.com/login";
    String dashURL = "http://members.permaculturedesigncourse.com/dashboard";
    String sUserName = "myemail@gmail.com";
    String sPass = "mypassword";

    try {

        Connection.Response login_get_res = Jsoup
                .connect(loginURL)
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();

        Element mySession = login_get_res.parse().getElementById("new_user_session");
        String authenticityToken = mySession.select("input[name=authenticity_token]").first().val();
        Map<String, String> cookiesFromGet = login_get_res.cookies();


        Connection.Response login_post_res = Jsoup
                .connect(loginURL)
                .data("authenticity_token", authenticityToken)
                .data("user_session[email]", sUserName)
                .data("user_session[password]", sPass)
                .data("user_session[remember_me]", "0")
                .data("x", "0")
                .data("y", "0")
                .referrer(loginURL)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.101 Safari/537.36")
                .cookies(cookiesFromGet)
                .timeout(12000) 
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();
        Document return_page = login_post_res.parse();      
        String title = return_page.title();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Store all your data in a HashMap named data and submit that as the data field. For example,
I would do:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("userName", userName);
map.put("password", password);
map.put("somethingelse", value);
map.put("anotherthing", anothervalue);

Document doc = null;
try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(loginUrl).data(map).cookies(cookiesFromGet).post();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also I don't think .cookies() returns cookies as you tried to do here:

```
Map<String, String> cookiesFromGet = login_get_res.cookies();
```

I would try to use a HttpConnection to get the cookies. Like so:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(loginUrl);
HttpResponse response = null;
String responseString = null;
try {
    response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
    responseString = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

CookieStore cookieStore = ((AbstractHttpClient) httpClient).getCookieStore();
HashMap<String, String> cookies = new HashMap<String, String>();
cookies = mapCookies(cookieStore.getCookies());
```

Finally, you might have to make some changes to your site code to check if POST variables were sent and display user content instead of the login page. I can't tell if you've done this because I haven't seen your web code.

Comment: I appreciate the extra edit, but your reference to AbstractHttpClient is deprecated. I might have gotten it to take by changing to:

Comment: I appreciate the extra edit, but your reference to AbstractHttpClient is deprecated. I might have gotten it to take by changing to:

CookieStore cookieStore = (CookieStore) ((AbstractHttpClient) httpClient).getCookieStore();
      
But your mapCookie() method doesn't resolve out. 

Also, I might have mispoke, but this is not MY site I'm trying to log into. I have an account on another company's site. So I am unable to "make some changes to your site code to check if POST variables were sent"